# Problem installing gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Why do I get this error every time I type `gem install gem_name`?

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml
```

gem -v = 1.0.1, ruby -v = 1.8.6

Comment: It could be that your rubygems is outdated or a proxy setting is redirecting the request. Can you check what you're running? I tried installing a gem and had no problems.

Comment: Mentioning your ruby version and rubygems version might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gem 1.0.1 is very old, you should update it first.

Probably

`gem --update system`

is also broken, so you should install a new version manually.

And [this is probably the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025583/i-cant-install-any-gem-or-updates-in-leopard).

Comment: helpful link to install new versions manually on OS X 10.5:  http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard/